# Is there any way to clone only particular folder/files in the plastic SCM instead of entire branch?

Tags: plasticscm

I want to copy/clone only particular files from repo.
I tried many ways using cm cmd line executable of plastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cm getfile --help
Downloads the content of a given revision.

Usage:

```
cm getfile | cat <revspec> [--file=<output_file>] [--debug]
                 [--symlink] [--raw]

revspec           Object specification. (Use 'cm help objectspec' to learn
                  more about specs.)
```

Options:

```
--file            File to save the output. By default, it is printed on the
                  standard output.
--debug           When a directory specification is used, the command
                  shows all the items in the directory, its revision id
                  and file system protection.
--symlink         Applies the operation to the symlink and not to the
                  target.
--raw             Displays the raw data of the file.
```

Examples:

```
cm cat myfile.txt#br:/main
(Obtains the last revision in branch 'br:/main' of 'myfile.txt'.)

cm getfile myfile.txt#cs:3 --file=tmp.txt
(Obtains the changeset 3 of 'myfile.txt' and write it to file 'tmp.txt'.)

cm cat serverpath:/src/foo.c#br:/main/task003@myrepo
(Obtains the contents of '/src/foo.c' at the last changeset of branch
'/main/task003' in repository 'myrepo'.)

cm cat revid:1230@rep:myrep@repserver:myserver:8084
(Obtains the revision with id 1230.)

cm getfile rev:info\ --debug
(Obtains all revisions in the 'info' directory.)
```